# Deserialization a JSON in iOS with error

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, deserialization

I´m a total newbie in iOS development. I´m trying to connect to a JSON service that give me this response:

"{\"SessionId\":\"e0750994-9d68-429d-af2c-e149986a8ce0\"}"

I´m trying to deserialize to a:

```
  NSDictionary *parsedObject = 
  [NSJSONSerialization 
  JSONObjectWithData:objectNotation 
  options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments 
  error:&localError];
```

But it´s fail because it says that is not a Dictionary.

I´ve tried to NSArray and with TouchJson and I´ve received the same error.

I only can deserialize to an NSString, but been an string is not possible access by key.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Watch out: `parsedObject` can be a `NSDictionary` or a `NSArray` - depends on the input string/object. Usually you parse to an `id` and later check its type.

Comment: @rokjarc: That's good advice. (In this case, it is an NSString.)

Comment: It should be a `NSDictionary` with one key-value pair. I guess the raw data is not (un)escaped correctly. `{"SessionId":"e0750994-9d68-429d-af2c-e149986a8ce0"}`should give you a single dictionary and a `[{"SessionId":"e0750994-9d68-429d-af2c-e149986a8ce0"}]` would give you an array that contains one dictionary.

Comment: @MartinR: you might want to put your first comment as an answer. Just to keep things tidy & answered :)

Comment: @rokjarc: I already voted to close as a duplicate, which seems appropriate here. It is not necessary to repeat my answer from the duplicate question.

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  Takes 5-10 minutes to learn.  Then understand that when you use NSLog to dump JSON data, NSArrays will dump surrounded with `()` characters and NSDictionarys will dump surrounded with `{}` characters.  And if the data is "nested JSON" the `:` character in original JSON "objects" will remain unchanged and all the quotes will still be there, but if the data has been transformed the `:` will change to `=` and most quotes will have been removed (except around strings containing blanks or "odd" characters).